# How to remove listview dividerHeight after setting view.setVisibility as GONE

Tags: android, android-listview, visibility

I am using ViewHolder pattern and Custom Cursor Adapter.
But when i use setVisibility Gone a view, dividerHeight of row not realase space!

how can fix it ? thanks

Comment: Have you disabled the listviews divider?

Comment: you can use invalidate() method

Comment: @mustafasevgi how i can use ? view.invalidate(); ?

Comment: android:footerDividersEnabled="false"

Answer (score 3):

If you what exactly what you wrote in the question. Do this:

let each listView Item layout contain a TextView and a View(divider after each item), then depending on  the position parameter you get in the getView() method change the Height of the View.

ListView Item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="14dp" >
    </TextView>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/label"
        android:background="@drawable/orange" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

now in the adapter class your ViewHolder contains the TextView and also the View.

so,

```
Holder.View = (View)convertView.findViewById(R.id.view);
if(position == 0){
     (Holder.View).setHeight(2);
}
```

and so on.

Comment: no no, i not access to listView, i want just remove one row dividerHeight in bindView into CursorAdapter.

Comment: Can you please paste your code @MehdiEsmaeili or the other alternative could be not using listview dividers and put your custom divider in your custom view.

Comment: @ArslanAhmad yes i would if you have asked nicely rather than in offensive manner.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This Code:- 

<ListView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >
    </ListView>
```